# I'm getting an empty dataframe when I try to get Lebrons short chart

Tags: python, dataframe

Trying to get all of legions field goal attempts into a dataframe but I just get an empty dataframe when I try. What am I doing wrong?

```
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import shotchartdetail
from nba_api.stats.static import players
from nba_api.stats.static import teams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


players = players.get_players()
teams = teams.get_teams()

# Get LeBron's player id and team id
bron = [player for player in players if player['full_name'] == 'LeBron James'][0]
print(bron)
bron_id = bron['id']

lakers = [team for team in teams if team['full_name'] == 'Los Angeles Lakers'][0]
print(lakers)
lal_id = lakers['id']

shotlog_lebron = shotchartdetail.ShotChartDetail(team_id = 0, player_id = '2544',
context_measure_simple = 'FGA',
season_type_all_star = ['Regular Season', 'Playoffs'])

print(shotlog_lebron)
```

tried the above code